# Force local packet pass trough the router (or disable loopback) - windows 8

Tags: router, tcp, local, loopback

i would like to avoid that packets sent from my machine to the same machine (via the IP assigned by the external router eg. 192.168.1.20)  are routed with loopback and so never reach the external router.

In a few words, i want that a ping made from my PC to 192.168.1.120 go to the router and then come back to my PC.

I'm on Windows 8.1 but a solution for Windows 7 is appreciated.

thanks

---

I've tried to add a route (via `route add` ) setting as gateway the IP of my external router but the result is that the Ping doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  There is likely an easier way to accomplish whatever your goal is.

Comment: The goal is measure the delay of transmission in my network during the day with various packet sizes. It's for experimental pourposes.